# jquery mouse over and out event firing when mouse is moved quickly over image

Tags: jquery, mouse, fadein, out

I know this looks like a duplicate of: [jquery hover() mouseOut event not firing when mouse is moved quickly over link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957232/jquery-hover-mouseout-event-not-firing-when-mouse-is-moved-quickly-over-link) but is not working for me.
I'm PHP programmer without knowledge of javascript or jquery.
Right now I'm trying to make a very simple icon animation, got 2 images, when mouse is over, it changes to the second image, whith jquery fadeIn fadeOut functions. Very simple.
Like in the link above, I make a callback function to fire the fadeOut effect when mouse pointer is out, but when I slightly move the mouse over, the event fires up again, and again. I hope I make myself clear (newbie english speaker).
This is the code so far:

```
<img src="<?= base_url(); ?>img/face1.jpg" id="icon"> //<-- this function is from codeigniter, to get the base url
```

and the jQuery function (in a separate file):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#icon").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to use [**.mouseenter()**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).

In that case you just get 1 event, while with mouseover you get many.
So your code could be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#icon").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

You could also do this just with CSS:

```css
#icon {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
#icon:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6" id="icon" alt="" />
```

Comment: this solved my question back then, but I didn't know how to vote hehe, thanks Sergio!

Comment: @diegoalmesp you are welcome. If you want you can also up-vote :) Btw, just added also a CSS version, always better than jQuery! http://jsfiddle.net/g995b05g/